# Can't copy a file shared only with me

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

A user shared with me a link (shared with just me.........llama@bowlcut.com). I try to copy the file but I get an error `"File not found"`.

```
def copy_file(service, origin_file_id, copy_title):
    try:
        print service.files().copy(fileId=origin_file_id, body={'title': copy_title}).execute()
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
```

If the user changes the share policy to share with everyone & creates a link (the file number doesn't change) and I rerun it then I am able to copy it. Why aren't I able to copy a file someone shares with just me?

Comment: tried adding the google-drive-api tag but it won't let me for some reason

Comment: You probably need to authenticate the code with an access token.

Comment: If you are not authenticating, it should give "you do not have permission" not " File not found" error I guess.

Comment: @KRR: exactly. I am authenticated...the issue is that it doesn't seem to be reading all my files....just the files that particular app created.

Comment: Which OAuth scope are you using? If you use Drive.File you can only access files created or opened by your app. So if your friend is sharing an arbitrary file with you, your app will still not be able to access it. You need the 'Drive' or 'Drive.Readonly' scope to be able to access files that were not created by your app.

Comment: @GrantWatters I am using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive. I can copy files that are shared with everyone...just not files that were shared exclusively with me.

Comment: Do you have read access to the file?

Comment: I've tried it with "can view" "can edit" and "can comment" with no luck. When I get a shareable link it works under all 3 circumstances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is make sure the user is logged in.